# How to add Google maps to my working android Application [blank activity with fragments]?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am having some trouble adding Google map to my android application. It works independently but not when i add the codes to my application. I believe it is because for the independent application with Google maps, i selected the Google Maps activity at first. But for the other one, it is a normal activity.
May i know what codes do i have to add or remove to make the Google map work?
My Application includes fragments for swipe tabs and slide navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-and-place-details-using-google-places-api-and-google-maps-android-api-v2/) You will get a fair concept how to use Google map.